# Java method calculate("2.002*1000") //returns 2001.999999999999

Tags: java, evaluation

I've made a method calculate(String) to evaluate the operand in type String, for example "2+3".
I have tried lots of operand and the method works fine except this:
calculate("2.002*1000) //returns 2001.9999999999
I'm so curious how could this error occurred. I'd gone through the code many times and I can't figure out where the problem.

Here the code:

```
private String calculate(String str)
    {
        String num = "";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) //Arrange str into list, elements are seperated by "+" or "-"
        {
            if(! checkPM(str.substring(i, i + 1)))
            {
                num = num + str.substring(i, i + 1);
            } else
            {
                list.add(num);
                list.add(str.substring(i, i + 1));
                num = "";
            }
        }
        list.add(num);//add the last num into list
        if(checkSign(list.get(list.size() - 1)))//remove last element if it is an operator
        {
        list.remove(list.get(list.size() - 1));
        }
        String numlistele = ""; //Elements of numlist
        List<String> numlist = new ArrayList<String>(); //List of numbers to be TD
        List<String> TDlist = new ArrayList<String>(); //List of times or divide
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) //Check which of the elements of list contains "*" or "/"
        {
            String tdAns = ""; //Answer of numlistele timed or divided
            if(checkTD(list.get(j))) // When the elements of list contains "*" or "/"
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < list.get(j).length(); k++) //
                {
                    if(! checkSign(list.get(j).substring(k, k + 1)))
                    {
                        numlistele = numlistele + list.get(j).substring(k, k+1);
                    } else
                    {
                        numlist.add(numlistele);
                        TDlist.add(list.get(j).substring(k, k+1));
                        numlistele = "";
                    }
                }
                numlist.add(numlistele); //Adds the last number into numlist
                numlistele = ""; //Restore numlistele to "", to be used in next loop 
                tdAns = numlist.get(0); //Answer of numlistele timed or divided, firstly it is equals to the first elements of numlist
                for(int l = 0; l < TDlist.size(); l++)
                {
                    if(TDlist.get(l).equals("×"))
                    {
                        double tempdou = Double.parseDouble(tdAns) * //temporary double used to save to tdANS
                                Double.parseDouble(numlist.get(l+1));
                        tdAns = String.valueOf(tempdou);
                    } else //when TDlist.get(l).equals("/") is true
                    {
                        double tempdou = Double.parseDouble(tdAns) / 
                                Double.parseDouble(numlist.get(l+1));
                        tdAns = String.valueOf(tempdou);
                    }
                }
            list.set(j, tdAns);
            }               
            numlist.clear(); //Clear numlist for next loop
            TDlist.clear(); //Clear TDlist for next loop
        }
        String ans = list.get(0); //Will become final answer later, first it is assign to first element of list
        for(int m = 0; m < list.size(); m++)
        {
            if(list.get(m).equals("+"))
            {
                double tempdou = Double.parseDouble(ans) + //Temporary double used to save to ans
                        Double.parseDouble(list.get(m + 1));
                ans = String.valueOf(tempdou);
            } else if(list.get(m).equals("-"))
            {
                double tempdou = Double.parseDouble(ans) - 
                        Double.parseDouble(list.get(m + 1));
                ans = String.valueOf(tempdou);
            }
        }
        if(ans.length() > 2)
        {
            if(ans.substring(ans.length() - 2).equals(".0")) //To remove .0 of the answer
            {
                ans = ans.substring(0, ans.length() - 2);
            }

        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Nambari I was about to post that myself

Answer (score 6):

Floating point representations are not always that accurate.  When you've parsed the string "2.002", `Double.parseDouble` returned the closest possible `double` representation.

When multiplied by `1000`, the error in floating point representation became large enough to notice (2001.999999999999).

Here's a [good online article about floating point representation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/) and the mishaps that can occur.

To ensure accurate representation of a floating point number, you can use Java's built-in [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.  It may not be as fast, but it will retain all the precision you need.

Answer (score 4):

It happens because doubles are rounded due to IEEE 754 rounding rules. 
If you don't want to round them, use BigDecimal class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: It's nice that you've offered a bit of a solution to the problem in addition to an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a textbook case of floating point mathematics.  What you multipled wasn't actually 2.002 * 1000.  instead, it was a number reeeeeeeeally close to 2.002 multiplied by a number reeeeeeeeally close to 1000.

If you need absolute precision, you should use something java's `BigDecimal` type.  In C#, you would use the `decimal` type.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point